# WPF MVVM - How can I pass two variables from the ViewModel associated with the first window to the second ViewModel associated with the second window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I don't want to use Prism or MVVM Light solutions and would like to pass two parameters to the second window? How could I do that? I was looking for some information on this topic, but unfortunately most of them use packages...

Comment: Use the same view model object for both Windows.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason why not getting help from those kind of libraries? I'd strongly suggest give it a try. Especially the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-dotnet-community-toolkit-800/). It's part of the .NET foundation and it will make your life easier and make your project cleaner and stable.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding i can't use IT because, It is one of condition to pass exam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

App.xaml

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="YourViewModel" />
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="ABC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC"
        DataContext="{StaticResource YourViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeVar}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

SecondWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="ABC.SecondWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC"
        DataContext="{StaticResource YourViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SecondWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeVar}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: But your "SomeVar" is the same in Main and Second Window ? And you are using the same ViewModel?

Comment: @Laos yes it's the same

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just send parameters in the constructor of the second window, wherever you are creating your window.

```
var newwin = new SecondWindow("second param is int", 42 );
newwin.Show();
```

And then just create an another constructor for your window:

```
public SecondWindow(string a, int b) : this()
{
    var secondVM = (SecondViewModel)DataContext;
    secondVM.IAmSendingYouTwoParams( a,b);
... 
}
```